# What are examples of parallelizable complex projective varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

A [smooth complex projective variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_variety) is the zero-locus, inside some $\mathbb{CP}^n$, of some family of homogeneous polynomials in $n+1$ variables satisfying a certain number of conditions that I won't spell out. It is in particular a differentiable manifold. A [parallelizable manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold) is a (differentiable) manifold with a trivial tangent bundle, i.e. $TM \cong M \times \mathbb{R}^n$ (equivalently, a manifold of dimension $n$ is parallelizable if it admits $n$ vector fields that are everywhere linearly independent).

Being a projective variety is an algebro-geometric condition, whereas being parallelizable is more of a algebro-topological condition. I'd like to know how the two interact. For example, according to Wikipedia, some [complex tori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_torus) are projective. But like all Lie groups, a complex torus is parallelizable.

> What are other examples of smooth complex projective varieties that are parallelizable?

Comment: Interesting question (+1). Is there any particular reason to believe that parallelizability of complex projective varieties can be characterized algebraically? To be specific, what's the motivation behind looking for complex projective varieties which are parallelizable? I'd be interested in hearing it (although it's unlikely I'd understand much).

Comment: @BalarkaSen I don't really know much about algebraic geometry, to be honest. Even a few examples would be helpful. But I know that some theorems that have apparently nothing to do with algebraic geometry can be proven for some classes of algebraic manifolds (e.g. Kähler manifolds are formal, a property that's only interested in the rational homotopy of the space). So maybe there's something interesting to be said here. As for the motivation: I have a construction that works only for parallelizable manifolds, and I know it's supposed to yield a result for complex projective varieties.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very interesting fact you have mentioned up there (although I only vaguely know what a Kahler manifold is). I'd be excited to know if parallelizability of complex protective varieties can be inferred completely algebraically, though. Hopefully people would have something nice to say in the answers.

Comment: For curves, all you get is tori. For surfaces, you can't possibly be simply connected lest $\chi(M) \neq 0$. I guess that again all you're left with are tori but don't have a proof off the top of my head. Maybe a thorough look at CY 3-folds is the next thing to do; this is one dimension more than my knowledge.

Comment: One more comment: @MikeMiller's comment got me thinking about how one could really prove that for complex surfaces the only possibility is a torus. It seems hard! About all I can say for sure at the moment is that a (smoothly) parallelisable surface can't contain a curve which has odd intersection number with the canonical bundle. In particular, it must be minimal.

Comment: @Schemer: I am not an algebraic geometer. What does minimal mean? Not obtained as a blowup of some other surface? (Also, looking a bit through the classification, it seems believable that some hyperelliptic surfaces could be parallelizanle.)

Comment: @MikeMiller: yes, minimal means not the blowup of another smooth surface. If $X \rightarrow Y$ is a blowup, then the exceptional curve has intersection -1 with the canonical bundle $K_X$, hence my previous comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At Najib Idrissi's request, here is an answer to a different question:

> **Theorem:** the only Kaehler manifolds which are *holomorphically* parallelisable are complex tori.

Reference:

Wang, Hsien-Chung. Complex parallisable manifolds. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **5** (1954), 771–776.

**Edit:** OK, here's a way to get a family of examples containing those given by Michael Albanese.

> **Proposition:** If $M$ is a parallelisable (real) manifold of dimension $d \geq 1$, and $C$ is any orientable (real) surface, then $M \times C$ is parallelisable.

*Proof:* $C$ embeds in $\mathbf R^3$, so (e.g. thinking about an outward unit normal vector) we see that the tangent bundle of $C$ is trivialised by adding one copy of the trivial bundle over $C$:
$$TC \oplus \mathbf R_C = \mathbf R^3_C.$$
Now the tangent bundle of $M \times C$ is $\pi_1^* TM \oplus \pi_2^* TC$, which by hypothesis is $$\pi_1^* \mathbf R_M^d \oplus \pi_2^* TC = \mathbf R_{M\times C}^{d-1} \oplus \pi_2^* (T_C \oplus \mathbf R_C) = \mathbf R_{M\times C}^{d+2}. \quad \square$$

> **Corollary:** Any complex manifold of the form $A \times C_1 \times \cdots \times C_n$ where $A$ is a complex torus of positive dimension and the $C_i$ are Riemann surfaces is parallelisable.

*Proof of Corollary:* As the OP remarked, $A$ is parallelisable. Now apply the Proposition $n$ times. $\square$

Comment: Nice answer. I should have noticed that $\mathbb{CP}^1$ could be replaced by any Riemann surface. The general idea is that taking products of parallelizable manifolds with manifolds with stably trivial tangent bundles produces many more parallelizable manifolds.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a small, rather unsatisfying collection of examples arising from the following result:

> A (non-trivial) product of spheres is parallelizable if and only if at least one of the spheres is odd-dimensional.

One can ask whether any such products can be given a complex structure which makes them projective. First of all, such a manifold would be Kähler and hence symplectic. By considering the cohomology ring of such a product, we can see that the only possibilities are $(S^1)^{2m}\times(S^2)^k$ with $m > 0$. Such spaces have many projective complex structures. For $n = 0$, we obtain the projective tori that you already mentioned, together with their products. For $n > 0$, we get the product of a non-zero number of algebraic tori with $n$ copies of $\mathbb{CP}^1$.

Comment: ...I thought the only parallelizable spheres were of dimension 0, 1, 3, 7?

Comment: I don't see how anything I've written suggests otherwise.

Comment: Well $S^5$ is a product of spheres, at least one of them being odd-dimensional... Sorry if I misunderstand, I think there's something I'm missing.

Comment: I don't think so. If $S^5 = S^k\times M$ for some $k < 5$, then $\pi_k(S^5) = \pi_k(S^k)\times\pi_k(M) = \mathbb{Z}\times\pi_k(M) \neq 0$.

Comment: Ah! You mean a nontrivial product with at least two factors... Sorry for that. I'm too used to category theoretical conventions where e.g. the terminal object is an (empty) product... And this comes from the fact that the tangent bundle of a sphere is stably trivial right?

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right, my wording was not clear, I will edit accordingly. Yes, I believe it follows from stable triviality, but I haven't completely read through the proof yet.

Comment: Odd-dimensional spheres have a nonvanishing vector field. Use this to pull off a $\Bbb R$ factor and trivialize one of the other sphere's tangent bundles; then use this trivialization to add a $\Bbb R^2$ factor to what's left of the tangent bundle of your odd-dimensional sphere to trivialize it, then use these to trivialize the rest, etc. Products of even-dimensional spheres aren't parallelizable because of the Euler characteristic.